# Refresh view in a TabItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a view in my first tab that changes data in a DatageStorageController. When I click the second tab it is supposed to show the datastorage but the view is not updated. How can I refresh the view? It is not a UITable View just a View.

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand your question. can you illustrate a bit more? are you using a `UITabBarController`? what do you mean by "changes data in a blabla"? like `[tableView reloadData];`? Is the second view the same as the first or different?

Comment: Yes I'm using a UITabBarController with 2 relationships (tab bar items) that are both navigation controllers. They both push to a view controller. In the first one data is changed using sharedInstance. In the second one the view displays the data but the data doesn't display the updated data. The views use different classes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are write code into viewDidLoad. You should write this code into viewWillAppear Which do you want to update. on ViewAppear.
OR 
Second method you can use delegate method of tabbarcontroller

Like

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

With this method you can receive argument viewController which you are selected.

[viewController viewDidLoad];

It's mean you load view again.
you also call 
[viewController viewWillAppear];

Answer (score 0):

well, you could implement the [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and update your controllers view in 
'tabBar:didSelectItem'. But this approach is maybe not the most clean one! The second controller should somehow be notified on data changes, so that he can update its view. Maybe take a look at KVO/KVC!